# Creating multiple branches/streams in RTC source control

Tags: rtc

What is the standard method of creating multiple streams of development of the same project in RTC source control?

Currently to create a single stream I create a repository workspace & its corresponding stream. I check in the project to the workspace and then deliver it to this new stream. To create a new stream of development for the project do I need to repeat this process or is there a better way, maybe using the command line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,  you don't need to repeat the process.

I would recommend putting a baseline on the component you delivered in the first stream. Or put a snapshot on the first stream. That will label all the components in that stream.

Then you create a second stream, which you can :

- fill component by component, specifying for each one a baseline
- or specifying directly at snapshot, which will put all the components with their associated labels in that new stream.

Then you create your repository workspace and start working.

So the idea behind a *new* stream is to specify from what version you want to start working.
Hence the baselines or snapshot put in the first stream : that will help initialize the next stream.
Without having to re-import everything.